# MS Edge handling of ajax calls to web service when unauthorised

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, microsoft-edge

My website uses Forms authentication. If I make ajax calls to my web service and the user's authentication has expired, I would expect the error routine in my ajax call to be called. However in MS Edge I see a console log of:

```
HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication
(XHR) POST - http://mywebserviceurl
```

I then see the success routine in my ajax call triggered with a responseText of the whole of the html for my website home page.

Is this expected behaviour or have I misinterpreted what is going on?

I am trying to get round this by checking whether the user is logged in before I make the ajax call but this feels like it should be unnecessary.